# Media Queries - How was this achieved

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I stumbled across this page: http://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Bold-Headline-Responsive-Minimalist-Blogger-Template.jpg

I started playing with the width of the page and I was wondering how the particular effect of the "Page Not Found" text growing and shrinking was achieved relative to the right-hand-side grey block.

I know there is a fixed width on the header, but does the white portion of the page fall within those same fixed width dimensions and then just follow a media query specification or is something else going on?

Comment: I don't see any font size changes?

Comment: Because it doesn't. 
And there is no media query either.
It's just a width in %age and a margin in %age.